# ReactNavigationStack Header Style is not working only he change the header background Color

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

if anyone tries this so please help me, I am trying to change the border colour top and bottom in the header in react-native stack navigation , Anyone tries this please help me to sort this problem
This is the Code in which we use the header style to change the header border and width

<Stack.Navigator

```
  >
    {state.token == null ? (
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    ) : (
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Dull"
        component={Tabs}
        options={{
          // headerStyle: styles.header,
          headerShown: false,
          title: "Clubs",
          headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
          headerTitleAlign: "center",
          headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#080402",
          },
        }}
      />
    )}
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Forget"
      component={ForgetPassword}
      options={{
        // headerStyle: styles.header,
        title: "Forget Password",
        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#080402" },
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Profiles"
      component={ProfileScreen}
      options={{
        // headerStyle: styles.header,
        title: "Profile",
        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#080402" },
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Tabs"
      component={Tabs}
      options={{
        // headerStyle: styles.header,
        title: "Password Reset",
        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#080402" },
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Du"
      component={Home}
      options={({ route, navigation }) => ({
        title: route.params.itemname,

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
        },
        headerRight: () => <Header />,
      })}
    />
    {/* <Stack.Screen
      name="Dull"
      component={Tabs}
      options={{
        // headerStyle: styles.header,
        title: "Clubs",
        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#080402" },
      }}
    /> */}
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Dum"
      component={Dummy}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: route.params.productTitle,

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
          borderBottomColor: "#85106a",
          borderBottomWidth: 5,
          borderTopWidth: 5,
          borderTopColor: "#85106a",
        },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Venue"
      component={Book}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Book Venue",

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
          elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
          shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS

          borderColor: "#B49C72",
          borderBottomWidth: 2,
          borderBottomColor: "red",
          borderTopWidth: 2,
          borderTopColor: "red",
        },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Queues"
      component={Queue}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Queue Jump",
        borderBottomWidth: 0,

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
        },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Forgets"
      component={Formessage}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Forget Password",

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#080402" },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Resets"
      component={Resetmessage}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Reset Password",

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
        },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Res"
      component={ResetPassword}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Reset Password",

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
        },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Map"
      component={Map}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Queue Jump",

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
          borderBottomColor: "#B49C72",
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderTopColor: "#B49C72",
        },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Ver"
      component={Verfied}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Queue Jump",

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
          borderBottomColor: "#B49C72",
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderTopColor: "#B49C72",
        },
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Un"
      component={Unverified}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: "Queue Jump",

        headerTintColor: "#B49C72",
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#B49C72" },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#080402",
          borderBottomColor: "#B49C72",
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderTopColor: "#B49C72",
        },
      })}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: check the updated

Answer (score 2):

I think this docs page provide what you want. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#header-related-options

And here is an example of setting border colour black with width of 2.

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerStyle: {borderColor: '#000', borderWidth: 2} }}>
{screens}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: You should post your navigator so we know how you wrote it. Maybe it is just a syntax error.

Comment: <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#080402",
            borderBottomColor: "#85106a",
            borderBottomWidth: 5,
            borderTopWidth: 5,
            borderTopColor: "#85106a",
          },